# Appending query strings from multiple pages

Tags: javascript

I'm currently stumped on this. I've snooped around for a bit and haven't found any concrete answer **using just JS** to do this, and so my question is thus. If I am navigating multiple pages and want to keep query strings from the one before attached to the url, what is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: You can use cookies.Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253821/persist-javascript-variables-between-get-requests

Comment: I was considering it, but if someone clears their cache it will lose all of their data thus far.

Comment: @CharlesLillo: Thats what's clearing cache is intended to do... Query strings are not made for data transferring, what do you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am aware of this... was just wondering if I was overlooking an easy way to do it =/. A post-get method would work, but I don't know if I can use php in what I am doing. I am working on a mobile app using jquery mobile, and am storing data between pages as a user nests through. The quickest way in my mind was query strings but that really isn't for nesting.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Remember to upvote ALL useful answers, including those to others' questions. And "check" (accept) the answer that best solves your own questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this if the way the user "navigates" is by using links within the pages.

1. In a given html page, Javascript running within the page can see the url's query parameters via the `window.search` property. [Mozilla docs.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location)
2. Then use JS to modify all of the page's anchor elements' href links to add on the already existing query parameters to the links.

Result: clicking on a link in the page will result in the new page having both the existing and new query parameters.

Comment: This is what I initially thought. If there is no easier way, I might just end up doing this. I have a feeling this is really the only way though.

Comment: Your only choices are this, cookies, or maintaining state on the server. Note that people can (and do) edit the urls. Also, there is a limit to url / query parameter lengths.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an easy way. You will have to take in account the current query parameters every time you compose a URL or create a form.

Comment: The only way I can think of is writing a script that grabs the next query string and appends it with the last, continuously doing so.

Comment: @CharlesLillo Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Doing what @LarryK said in a sense, but I was trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for this one?

```
var url1 = "...", url2 = "...";

var query1 = url1.split("#")[0].split("?").slice(1).join("?");
if (!query1)
    return url2;
var parts2 = url2.split("#");
parts2[0] +=  (parts2[0].indexOf("?")>-1 ? "&" : "?" ) + query1;
return parts2.join("#");
```

This extracts the query string from `url1` and appends it to the query string of `url2`, returning the new `url2`.